# EWS foreach all unread messages does not work

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I need to loop through all unread messages in inbox and download first attachment for every email, my code works but only for first email, why ?

```
/* load all unread emails */
SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, new ItemView(1));

/* loop through emails */
foreach (EmailMessage item in findResults)
{
    item.Load();

    /* download attachment if any */
    if (item.HasAttachments && item.Attachments[0] is FileAttachment) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Attachments[0].Name);
        FileAttachment fileAttachment = item.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;

        /* download attachment to folder */
        fileAttachment.Load(downloadDir + fileAttachment.Name);
    }

    /* mark email as read */
    item.IsRead = true;
    item.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
}

Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

in my inbox it set the first email to read but the sript stops then and write "Done." to console window. Whats wrong ?

Comment: Could it be your changing the collection while in the iteration over the collection? What will findResults.Count return before you start the loop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you're only requesting a single item from Exchange.

```
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(
    WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, 
    sf, 
    new ItemView(1));
```

The [ItemView class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.itemview(v=exchg.80).aspx) constructor takes a page size as its parameter, which is defined as:

> The maximum number of items the search operation returns.

So you're requesting a single item, which explains why your `foreach` completes after that one item.

To test this you can simply increase the `pageSize` to something more reasonable, like 100 or 1000.

But to fix it you should follow the idiomatic double-loop:

```
SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
do {
    findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, view);
    foreach (var item in findResults.Items) {
        // TODO: process the unread item as you already did
    }
    view.Offset = findResults.NextPageOffset;
}
while (findResults.MoreAvailable);
```

Here we continue retrieving more items from Exchange (in batches of 100) as long as it tells us there are more items available.

Answer (score 2):

public  void readMail()
        {

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("uname", "password", "domain");
        service.Url = new Uri("URL");
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

        SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, searchFilter, new ItemView(int.MaxValue));
            foreach (EmailMessage item in findResults.Items)
            {

                    item.Load();
                    if (item.HasAttachments)
                    {
                        foreach (var i in item.Attachments)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                FileAttachment fileAttachment = i as FileAttachment;
                                 fileAttachment.Load("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Desktop\\comstar\\Download\\test\\" + fileAttachment.Name);
                            }

                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.Write(e);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    //set mail as read 
                    item.IsRead = true;
                    item.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);

                }

    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.